# Convertir VARCHAR a VARBINARY (SQL)

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, conversión-de-tipos

estaba creando un procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server y me saltó este error de conversión. **"Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."**

La idea es encriptar y desencriptar passwords.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Login @email VARCHAR(30), @pass VARCHAR(25)
AS
DECLARE @PassEncode VARBINARY(8000)
DECLARE @PassDecode  VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @result  BIT
BEGIN
SELECT @PassEncode = contraseña FROM Usuario WHERE email = @email
SET @PassDecode = DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('password', @PassEncode)
END
BEGIN
IF @PassDecode = @Pass
BEGIN
SET @result=1
SELECT @result
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @Result=0
SELECT @result
END
END
Go
```

Por lo que leí tengo que usar "CONVERT" pero no sé en donde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cómo se explica en [la documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188910.aspx) la función `DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` devuelve un `VARBINARY` pero has definido tu variable `PassDecode` como un `varchar`.

Tienes 2 opciones, o hacer un `convert` de esa función o modificar el código para trabajar con `VARBINARY`. Entiendo que siempre es mejor modificar lo mínimo posible por lo que para hacer el `Convert`:

```
SET @PassDecode = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('password', @PassEncode), 2)
```

Te en cuenta que has definido `PassDecode` como un `varechar(25)`, quizá se puede quedar corto (o no). Si te da un error de tamaño aumenta tanto en su definición cómo en el convert el tamaño del `varchar`.